# How to display shortcuts in Eclipse menu bar for a menuitem?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Using extension points I have created a new menu item in menubar. My requirement is to display the shortcut name along with the menu name. For example, in Help Menu I have added a menuitem as "Tutorial". But I want to display it along with the shortcut say Ctrl+Alt+T. Shortcut is working but need to display the same in the menubar.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show the code/extension xml you used

Comment: <command 
         commandId="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial"
         label="Tutorial"
         style="push">
</command>
   
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
   <command
            id="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial"
            name="Tutorial">
      </command>
</extension><key 
  commandId="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial"
  schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
  contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.workbenchMenu"
  sequence="M1+M3+N">
</key>

Comment: Please edit the question and add decently formatted xml

Comment: Hey I've put that in formatted text but it is appearing in the comment as is...I'll split my code n post...

Comment: <command 
 commandId="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial" 
 label="Tutorial" style="push"> 
</command>

Comment: <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">                                       <command                                           id="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial"                               name="Tutorial">                                                                  </command>                                                                         </extension>

Comment: <key                                                 commandId="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial" schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"                          contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.workbenchMenu"     sequence="M1+M3+N">                                                                         </key>

Comment: <command  commandId="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial"  label="Tutorial" style="push">  </command>  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">  <command  id="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial"  name="Tutorial">  </command>  </extension>  <key  commandId="com.pat.tool.command.tutorial"  schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"  contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.workbenchMenu"  sequence="M1+M3+N">  </key>

Answer (score 0):

High level todo list. In your e4xmi file (model):

- add a binding context (BC)
- add a binding table (BT) for the Binding context
- link your menuitem to a command
- in the BT, add a Keybinding (eg M1 +T for Ctrl T), link it to the command
- link the BC to your main window (add the BC to the list of Binding context in the Trimmed Window attributes ) (or the artefact where the menu bar is attached)

As the keybinding is linked to a command, everywhere you use the command (menu, toolbar etc.) the shortcut will be displayed